# Problem regarding "With" function

Tags: equation-solving, functions, scoping

I am trying to calculate the effective potential using this code in Mathematica:

```
f[r_] := 1 - (2*M)/r + Q^2/r^2 + r^2/l^2;
M = (rp/2)*(1 + Q^2/rp^2 + rp^2/l^2);
L = 1;
Subscript[V, eff][r_] := f[r]*(L^2/r^2 + \[Delta]1);
r0 = (l/2)*((3/2)*rp*(Q^2/rp^2 + rp^2 + 1) + 
          Sqrt[(9/4)*rp^2*(Q^2/rp^2 + rp^2 + 1)^2 - 8*Q^2]);
\[Delta]1 = 0.0;
l = 1.0;
Q = 0.11;
With[{rp = 0.11}, Subscript[V, eff][r]]
```

which is not giving me the desired result. Why the function "With" is not working in this case?

Comment: What kind of equations do you want to solve?  I cannot see anyone, only definitions. What for have you you introduced r0 if it's not relevant to the problem you are asking for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alternatively you can use `Block`

```
Block[{rp = 0.11}, Subscript[V, eff][r]]
```

Answer (score 3):

"With" has the attribute "HoldAll". It will take the unevaluated input and replace according to the first argument. In your case, the unevaluated 2. argument does not contain "rp", therefore nothing is replaced.

To get what you want, you may evaluate the second argument by:

```
With[{rp = 0.11}, Evaluate[Subscript[V, eff][r]]]
```

[image]